# Inserting a node at a specific position in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Given a node class like

```
class Node {
     int data;
     Node next;
  }
```

Provide an implementation to Insert a node at a specific position in a linked list

```
Node insert(Node head, int data, int position) {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.next = null;

    if(head == null && position != 0) {
        return head;
    } else if(head == null && position == 0) {
        head = newNode;
        return head;
    }

    if(position == 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return head;
    }

    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
        if(current == null)
            break;
    }

    newNode.next = current;
    previous.next = newNode;
    return head;

}
```

Can you please critic my code and provide your thoughts on where I should improve my code.

Comment: You have the tags section for tags. Please don't put tags in the title.

Comment: I will make sure next time i do not do that. thank you.

Comment: there is no output at all.if you explain every step in code by keeping comments means it is more helpful for us.

Answer (score 2):

- **Avoid special cases**

  If `position == null` the new node becomes head no matter what, and you don't need to care what the head was before.

  Similarly, the validity of `position` is determined in a traversal loop (`if (current == null)` condition); testing specifically for `head == null && position != 0` is premature.

  BTW, the code handles invalid position inconsistently. Yet another cause to avoid special cases.
- **Avoid naked loops**

  Every loop does an important job, and deserves a name. The loop

  ```
  for(i = 0; i < position; i++)
  ```

  serves a purpose of finding a node at the particular position. Factor it out into a method and name it properly.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable tips, btw i made some changes in the code. can you please take a look at it.